# Creating and adding string values to a 2D array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Hi I want to create a string array in C that has 6 elements.

**Example:**

I want to save information such as firstName, lastName, accountNumber,  password, lastTransaction, balance.

I know how to do this in C# but can't get my head around it with C and the use of char[] arrays.

I want the output to be userAccount[0][0] Joe, userAccount[0][1] Bloggs, userAccount[0][2] 123456, userAccount[0][3] 1234, userAccount[0][5] 14 Aug, userAccount[0][0] $4.25.

Comment: `char *arr[] = {"one", "two", "three", ...};`, this is an array of pointers to non modifiable `char`s, or `char arr[][256] =  {"one", "two", "three", ...};` for a modifiable array (256 is the maximum length of each string in the array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a start:

```
static char* stateNames[] = 
{
  "David Hasselhoff",
  "Lady Gaga" ,
  "Jimmi Hendrix"
};

printf("SER: -> [%s]\n", stateNames[state]);
```

Comment: Used it as external static variable in a file. Known within the remainder of the source file in which it is declared. Used printf in a function within the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct userAccount{
 char name[50];
 char account[50];
 char pin[15];
};
```

struct is better to save the details

or

```
char input[5][256];
```

5= 5 peoples,
 256= 256 col

Answer (score 0):

C string is an array of `char`. In your case, array should be 3D, the first index for the number of members, the second for the number of fields of a member, the third for each string for a field of member info.

```
#define MEMBERS 1000 // The maximum number of members you want to store.
#define FIELDS 6     // (firstName)(lastName)(accountNumber)(password)(lastTransaction)(balance)
#define LENGTH 12    // The maximum length of field string

char info[MEMBERS][FIELDS][LENGTH] = {
    { "Joe", "Bloggs", "123456", "1234", "14 Aug", "$4.25" },
    ...
};
```